# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'NullBooleanField'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

After upgrading [djangorestframework](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework/) from `djangorestframework==3.13.1` to `djangorestframework==3.14.0` the code

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import NullBooleanField
```

Throws

> AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'NullBooleanField'

Reading [the release notes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#314x-series) I don't see a deprecation. Where did it go?

Comment: Aparently it is an issue in drf_spectacular: https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/816 that got fixed with `drf-spectacular==0.24.1`

Comment: I've added it to the drf project as a discussion:https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/8667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, there's a [deprecation warning](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/8599/files#diff-7768b980611e24de782acc70ad64cd57b9d169d42f80b200cb7c6ef277fd74dbL720) in the previous version, which also suggests a fix:

> The `NullBooleanField` is deprecated and will be removed starting with 3.14. Instead use the `BooleanField` field and set `allow_null=True` which does the same thing.

Comment: Side note: Django's `NullBooleanField` is also [removed in Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0)