# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'NullBooleanField' in Django inside Swagger

Tags: django, swagger, django-serializer

This error is thrown in django even though it's not even imported anywhere. It's thrown by OpenAPISchemaGenerator as follows:

```
 File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.13/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/field.py", line 406, in <module>
    (serializers.NullBooleanField, (openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN, None)),
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'NullBooleanField'
```

How do I fix this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823743/attributeerror-module-rest-framework-serializers-has-no-attribute-nullboolea). It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The support for NullBooleanField was removed in 3.14.0. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/812) on the `drf-yasg` github asking for support for this version of `drf`. They have also released a PR for this which is yet to be merged.

Answer (score 15):

NullBooleanField was removed in DRF 3.14.0 - see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/8599

Suggest to avoid 3.14.0 unless you can find another way to resolve..

```
djangorestframework>=3.13.1,!=3.14.0
```

Comment: The `NullBooleanField` is deprecated, so you would need to exclude *every* version starting from `3.14` upwards, *not* just `3.14.0`. However, I don't think that would be a proper solution either.

Comment: A true fix would be to use `BooleanField` instead, [as suggested in the deprecation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74221187).

Answer (score 6):

Which drf version do you use? I had the same issue today, changing from djangorestframework = "^3.13.1" to djangorestframework = "3.13.1" solved the issue. I guess today was the release of drf 3.14

Answer (score 3):

drf-yasg version 1.21.4, released Sep 27, fixes this.

```
FIXED: Remove NullBooleanFields if the django-rest-framework version >= 3.14.0 (#814)
```

https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/releases/tag/1.21.4